# Fastest way to iterates through records in file and replace contents on another file

Tags: language-agnostic

Need suggestions on the fastest way to read from a file containing list of values (~30k lines) and use the values to search and replace contents in another file (~500k lines) in Linux.

Currently I am iterating through the list file and forming the 'sed -e' commands then executing the command. However, it is taking ~1 hour to complete.

I'm looking to reduce the time taken by maybe 50%.

Here is a snippet of the code that I am currently using:

```
declare -a sedArgs

while IFS="" read -r line; do
    IFS=',' read -ra cols <<< ${line}

    col2=$(echo "${col2}" | sed 's/\*/\\*/g' | sed 's/\./\\./g')
    col4=$(echo "${col4}" | sed 's/\*/\\*/g' | sed 's/\./\\./g')

    sedArgs+=("-e")
    sedArgs+=("s|${col2}${col1}|${col4}${col3}|g")
fi
done < list.txt

sed -i "${sedArgs[@]}" target.txt
```

list.txt example:

```
OLDVAL1,1234,NEWVAL1,1222
OLDVAL2,2234,NEWVAL2,2222
```

target.txt example:

```
CUST1             OLDVAL1             1234 00000000000000000
CUST2             OLDVAL2             2234 00000000000000000
```

Comment: Don't use bash at all.  Perl is faster, python is faster, compiled languages (i.e. C) are even better.  Shell is ok for quick and dirty, but if you want performance, you have to go with languages that do not start a new shell every time you do something.

Comment: Please: post a precise statement of the problem ("search and replace" ... how?), your code, and a few lines of each file.  (In principle, build a hash/dictionary of the first file and use that for searching on the second ... but I can't tell whether that'll work with your problem, which isn't described)

Comment: define "fastest".

Comment: Embedding `sed` in a shell loop, while processing a text file will really make it very-very-very slow, but yeah you have 4 `sed` invocation in the loop, so that's times 4 slower...

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 2):

Build a hash with old-new pairs from the first file and use it for replacements

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Path::Tiny;  # for convenience to read a file

my $repl_data_file = 'list.txt';

my %repl = map { (split /,/)[0,2] } path($repl_data_file)->lines;

while (<>) { 
    s{\S+ \s+\K (\S+) (.*)}{ ($repl{$1}//$1) . $2 }ex;
    print
}
```

The `<>` operator reads line by line files with names given on the command line, so use this as `prog.pl target.txt > new_target.txt` (with output redirected to a file).

I make some assumptions since the description is sparse: the `list.txt` file has in the first and third column the old-new values, the value to replace in the target file is in the second column.

This should take mere seconds on the described files (sizes of 30k vs 500k lines).

---

I use [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) for convenience.  This is a very useful module to have and easy to install but here is an alternative with builtin tools only

```
my %repl =
    map { (split /,/)[0,2] }
    do { open my $fh, $repl_data_file or die $!; <$fh> };
```

Comment: I left it without explanations to not clutter the content --  let me know what needs clarification.